# Derive the indefinite integral of a Heaviside Function

Tags: special-functions

How can I prove that

$$\int H(x-a)dx=(x-a)H(x-a)+constant$$

where $H(x-a)$ represents a jumped Heaviside function

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Can you write what you have tried so far ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider [Ramp function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramp_function)
\begin{align}
R(x)
&= \dfrac{x+|x|}{2} \\
&= \begin{cases}x&x\geq0,\\0&x<0\end{cases} \\
&= x{\bf H}(x)
\end{align}
It's easy to see for $x\neq a$, $\dfrac{d}{dx}R(x-a)={\bf H}(x-a)$ then
$$\int{\bf H}(x-a)dx=R(x-a)+C=(x-a){\bf H}(x-a)+C$$

Comment: Thanks! I can understand more clearly from this answer

Comment: Your welcome.!.

Answer (score 0):

The Heaviside function is a piecewise step: $\mathcal H(x-a)=\begin{cases}1 &:& x-a\geqslant 0\\ 0 & :& x-a<0\end{cases}$

So consider the two cases, $x\geqslant a$ and $x<a$ for the directed integral $$\int \mathcal H(x-a)\mathrm d x = \mathscr c+ \begin{cases}\phantom+\int_a^x \mathcal H(s-a)\,\mathrm d s &:& x-a\geqslant 0\\ -\int_x^a \mathcal H(s-a)\,\mathrm d s & :& x-a<0\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0):

The function $H$ is piecewise constant, so that it is the derivative of a piecewise linear function. Furthermore, the slopes are $0$ then $1$.

We have

$$I(x):=\begin{cases}x\le a\to C_-,\\x\ge a\to C_++x.\end{cases}$$

To ensure continuity at $a$, $C_-=C_++a$ and

$$I(x):=\begin{cases}x\le a\to C,\\x\ge a\to C+x-a.\end{cases}$$

This is equivalent to

$$I(x)=C+(x-a)H(x-a).$$